# What should be the value of "h" in the definition of an nth order derivative?

Tags: python, python-2.7, derivative, calculus

I am trying to write a program for calculating the nth order derivative of any function which will be given by the user as an input using python 2.7.I have used the definition of nth order derivative(formally Grunwald-Letnikov derivative from fractional calculus but n is a natural number in my program).The problem is that for different(small)values of h,sometimes the output is incredibly errorfree from actual result and sometimes it is nowhere near it.
Also sometimes one value of h works for some function,and it doesnt-for some other.Also,one value of h works upto say 5th derivative giving more or less accurate results and suddenly from 6th derivative the result is vastly erroneus.What is the general form of h which i can take so that i get more or less correct answers of all functions for all orders of derivative?I am aware of modules like scipy,numpy,sympy which gives nth order derivatives in a line,but I am actually wanting to minimize the use of module functions,to gather more insight into the logic,so it is preferable if the code is modified without the use of packages or other modules.

The form of h I took is merely a guess,which incidentally worked for most polynomial functions(of all order),and trigonometric functions of upto atleast 2nd or 3rd order.
The code which i wrote is given below:

```
def Combination(n,r):
    return math.factorial(n)/float((math.factorial(n-r)*math.factorial(r)))
f=raw_input("enter the function:")
n=input("enter the order of derivative:")
h=10**(-(n+1))
a=input("enter the point at which the derivative is to be evaluated:")
sum=0
for i in range(0,n+1):
    x=a+(n-i)*h
    sum=sum+(((((-1)**i)*Combination(n,i))*eval(f)))/float(h**n)
print sum
```

5th and higher order derivatives of sine and cosine,4th and higher order of exp does not work,but for polynomial functions it works for almost all order of derivatives.

Comment: *h* is supposed to be an infinitesimal small number. But as you state yourself: the inverse operation is numerically unstable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability

Comment: Is there a certain form of h,which can be taken such that the operation is stable for all functions and all order derivatives?

Comment: It might be worth noting that division by 10^(-n) is equivalent to multiplication by 10^n.  Integer operations in python will have perfect accuracy.  If you can put off the cast to a float until *the very last thing*, you can usually get very good numerical stability out of whatever you are trying to do.  The way to accomplish this is to try and rearrange some stuff via algebra so that integer operations dominate the calculation.  An `int` times 10^n is another `int`.